# how can i create email template using Xml Odoo

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-8

how can i create email template using Xml  Odoo

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<openerp>

<data>
    <record id="entretien_send_email" model="email.template">
        <field name="name">Entretien Send by email</field>
        <field name="model_id" ref="model_appelsoffres_entretien"/>
        <field name="email_from">${(object.user_id.email or '')|safe}</field>
        <field name="subject">entretien</field>
        <field name="email_to">${(object.candidat.email or '')|safe}</field>
        <field name="auto_delete" eval="True" />
        <field name="subject">Your request has been submit</field>
        <field name="message"><![CDATA[
 THIS IS AN AUTOMATED EMAIL. DO NOT REPLY.

Hello,

We are here to inform you that the request [[object.candidat.nom]] est de    faire un entretien  [[object.titre_evenement]] with the following data:

    | Request - Details
    |=========================
    | Titre Evenement: [[object.titre_evenement]]
    |=========================
    | Nom Person: [[object.candidat.nom]]
    | Date Entretien: [[object.date_entretien]]
    | Heure Debut: [[object.heure_debut]]
    |=========================
    | Heure Fin: [[object.heure_fin]]


 Has not been confirmed and is closed.

 If you have any question, do not hesitate to contact your supervisor.

 Thank you!]]>
        </field>            
       </record>
      </data>
 </openerp>
```

and in python  I have

```
 class entretien(models.Model):

_name='appelsoffres.entretien'

titre_evenement = fields.Char(required=True)

candidat =fields.Many2one('appelsoffres.candidature',string="Candidat",required=True)

email = fields.Char(required=True)

telephone = fields.Char(required=True)

portable = fields.Char(required=True)

    state = fields.Selection([

    ('draft', "Brouillon"),

    ('confirmed', "Rendez Vous Planifié"),

    ('done', "Terminé"),

    ('sent', "Envoyé"),

], default='draft')

@api.multi
def action_draftentretien(self):
    self.state = 'draft'

@api.multi
def action_confirmentretien(self):
    self.state = 'confirmed'

@api.multi
def action_doneentretien(self):
    self.state = 'done'

@api.multi
def send(self):
    self.state = 'sent'

    et_pool = self.pool.get('email.template')
    mail_sent = et_pool.send_mail(
    self.env.cr, 1, entretien_send_email, force_send=True,  context=self.env.context)
 entretien()
```

I got following error:

```
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20160222\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 266, in wrapper

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-

20160222\server\openerp\addons\Appelsdoffres\AppelsOffres.py", line 224, in send

ValueError: "global name 'entretien_send_email' is not defined" while evaluating u'send()'
```

Comment: I was just wondering: the used tag is openerp-7 but you are clearly using the new API which was introduced by odoo v8. In the end you are mixing them. What version do you use?

Comment: Oh yes, thanks for the hint

Comment: No let them as they are. I was wondering about the mixing of old and new API at the end, too.

Comment: Warning!

Sender email is missing or empty after template rendering. Specify one to deliver your message

Comment: @CZoellner  I tried in every way, but to no avail. I worked with my email as sender  ,  Iworked with [<!CDATA['']] . 
            <field name="name">Entretien Send by email</field>
            <field name="model_id" ref="Appelsdoffres.model_appelsoffres_entretien"/>
            <field name="email_from"><![CDATA[${object.participants.name} <${(object.participants.email )|safe}>]]></field>
            <field name="subject">entretien</field>
            <field name="email_to">${(object.candidat.email or '')|safe}</field>

Comment: I worked  with $object            <field name="email_from">${(object.user_id.email or '')|safe}</field>
        <field name="subject">entretien</field>but always  the same problem

Comment: Your model 'appelsoffres.entretien' has no field 'user_id'. What about the field 'email' on that model? You have to know: 'object' in the dynamic context of template rendering is an instance (record or RecordSet) of your model. So you can just use its fields (and of course their relations).

Comment: @CZoellner  It works fine, it does not show error now. The problem is that I did not update the module I did only stop and start service. Now my problem is that the form email interface does not display

Comment: entretien_send_email = self.env.ref('Appelsdoffres.entretien_send_email',False)
        entretien_send_email.sudo().with_context().send_mail(self.id, True)
        result = {
        'name': 'Send Mail',
        'view_type': 'form',
        'view_mode': 'tree,form',
        'views': [('false', 'form'), ],
        'res_model':'appelsoffres.entretien',
        'context': 'ctx',
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'res_id': '1',
        'target': 'current',
        'context': {},
        }
        return result

Answer (score 3):

First of all make sure the xml file is loaded by the manifest file (__openerp__.py).

And your python code should be look like:

```py
@api.multi
def send(self):
    self.state = 'sent'
    # module_name should be replaced by the actual module name in which you have defined that custom template.
    entretien_send_email = self.env.ref('module_name.entretien_send_email')
    if entretien_send_email:
        entretien_send_email.send_mail(self.id)
```